# Save checkbox value in metabox

Tags: metabox

I created metabox for specific page template. Now I need to save checked or unchecked value of my checkbox. How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_home_meta');
function add_home_meta()
{
    global $post;

    if(!empty($post))
    {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if($pageTemplate == 'template-home.php' )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'home_meta', // $id
                'Homepage Options', // $title
                'display_home_meta', // $callback
                'page', // $page
                'normal', // $context
                'high'); // $priority
        }
    }
}

function display_home_meta() {
  global $post;
    // Add the HTML for the post meta
wp_nonce_field( 'avt_homepage_meta_box', 'avt_homepage_meta_box_nonce' );

      /*
       * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
       * from the database and use the value for the form.
       */
      $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_slider_display', true ); 
      ?>
      <p>
        <label for="avt_slider_slide_url">
            <strong><?php _e( 'Display slider on homepage:', 'avt' ); ?></strong>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="home_slider_display" value="true" />
      </p>
<?php    }

function avt_homepage_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

      // Check if our nonce is set.
      if ( ! isset( $_POST['avt_homepage_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
      }

      // Verify that the nonce is valid.
      if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['avt_homepage_meta_box_nonce'], 'avt_homepage_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
      }

      // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
      if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
      }

      // Check the user's permissions.
      if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
          return;
        }

      } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
          return;
        }
      }

      /* OK, its safe for us to save the data now. */

      // Make sure that it is set.
      if ( ! isset( $_POST['home_slider_display'] ) ) {
        return;
      }

      // Sanitize user input.
      $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['home_slider_display'] );

      // Update the meta field in the database.
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_slider_display', $my_data );
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'avt_homepage_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a WP question, but moreso a general form issue. Regardless, a checkbox will not pass **anything** if unchecked, and `1` or `on` if checked.

```
// Sanitize user input.
$my_data = $_POST['home_slider_display'] ? true : false;

// Update the meta field in the database.
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_slider_display', $my_data );
```