# Exclude pages by custom field (with yes/no) storing wrong data?

Tags: wp-list-pages, exclude

I might have a problem with the following codesnippet I came up with:

1.) I have a custom field (with custom fields plugin) that says YES or NO of "hide_menu_item"

2.) This is my loop to query the ids that have set checked the "hide_menu_item" checkbox.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'meta_key' => 'hide_menu_item',
      'meta_compare' => '!=',
    );
    $pages = get_posts($args);
    if ($pages) {
        $pageids = array();
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $pageids[]= $page->ID;
        }
    }
?>
```

3.) This is the wp_list_pages() that should exclude it then

```
<ul role="mobile-navigation">
    <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&exclude='.implode(",", $pageids)); ?>
</ul>
```

The problem I'm facing is, that this seemed to work. If I checked pages it they got excluded. But now when unchecking a page it is still excluded, and not shown again, so the toggle doesn't work.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Are you sure the checkbox is still unchecked when you refresh the edit page (is the unchecking saved)?

Comment: Yes, it is still unchecked, also after refresh: http://i.imgur.com/jzFHMaI.png

Comment: So the problem is not with your template but with [saving checkboxes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143449/save-checkbox-value-in-metabox).

Comment: But the saving should be done by the ACF Plugin, doesn't it. I hope you didn't get my answer wrong: The box is still unchecked, which should be unchecked, so the state is correctly saved. I want it unchecked, however it still isn't showing up in the nav -> it should just be hidden if checked.